# How to set ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayList values to TextView using for loop.I am try below code

Tags: android

I want to set arrayList values to TextView using for loop.I am try below code....

ArrayList> getStatusFlag_values = db.getStatusFlag();

```
        Log.i("", "getStatusFlag_values----->" + getStatusFlag_values);


        int count;


        for (count = 0; count < getStatusFlag_values.size(); count++) {

            final LayoutInflater layoutInflater =
                    (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
           final View jobView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.job_item_list_layout, null);


            TextView item_name_txt = (TextView) jobView.findViewById(R.id.item_name_txt);
            final TextView qnty = (TextView) jobView.findViewById(R.id.qnt);
            final TextView actual_qnt = (TextView) jobView.findViewById(R.id.actual_qnty);



            String _ItemName = getStatusFlag_values.get(count).get(DatabaseStaticVariable.KEY_ItemName);
            String _QtyExpected = getStatusFlag_values.get(count).get(DatabaseStaticVariable.KEY_QtyExpected);
            String _QtyActual = getStatusFlag_values.get(count).get(DatabaseStaticVariable.KEY_QtyActual);
            Log.i("", "_ItemName_bd_values------>" + _ItemName);
            Log.i("", "_QtyExpected_bd_values------>" + _QtyExpected);
            Log.i("", "_QtyActual_bd_values------>" + _QtyActual);


            item_name_txt.setText(_ItemName);
            actual_qnty_txt.setText(_QtyExpected);
            qnty_txt.setText(_QtyActual);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is correct, but are you adding the View you created (jobView) in your apps view?
also make sure this is done on main (Ui) thread.

Comment: Thank you.I add jobView in mainLayout and got answer.